# Comparing two Microsoft Excel files in Python

Tags: python

I have two Microsoft Excel files `fileA.xlsx` and `fileB.xlsx`

[fileA.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1il-50DjDTaAF_3e8wzOPDvdL3H-ImoS1/view?usp=sharing) looks like this:

[image: Content of fileA]

[fileB.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1piTxukzVA9iFzU7LUd3sLZvgyTWSQu9_/view?usp=sharing) looks like this:
[image: Content of fileB]

The Message section of a row can contain any type of character. For example: smileys, Arabic, Chinese, etc.

I would like to find and remove all rows from fileB which are already present in fileA. How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Panda's merge to first get the rows which are similar,
then you can use them as a filter.

```
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.read_excel("fileA.xlsx", dtype=str)
df_B = pd.read_excel("fileB.xlsx", dtype=str)
df_new = df_A.merge(df_B, on = 'ID',how='outer',indicator=True)
df_common = df_new[df_new['_merge'] == 'both']
df_A = df_A[(~df_A.ID.isin(df_common.ID))]
df_B = df_B[(~df_B.ID.isin(df_common.ID))]
```

df_A, df_B now contains the rows from fileA,fileB respectively without the common rows in both.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'am trying with using `pandas` and you have to also install `xlrd` for opening  xlsx files,

Then it will  take values from second file that are not in first file. Then creating a excel file name with second file name will rewrite the second file :

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')
b = pd.read_excel('b.xlsx')
diff = b[b!=a].dropna()

diff.to_excel("b.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
```

Comment: This gives me this error message: `raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled`